# Url parameter save to variable and reuse it in pagination links

Tags: php, url, get

I have this url:
http://localhost:8080/projects/mnhh/trunk/ee2/index.php/search?data%5Bcategories%5D%5B1%5D%5B%5D=11&data%5Bcategories%5D%5B2%5D%5B%5D=47&data%5Bcategories%5D%5B3%5D%5B%5D=3

This returns results which I paginate. I want to get the parameters and append them to the pagination links in order to maintain the search results when navigate between pages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search I found this function [http_build_query()](http://gr.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) which is exaclty what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = $_GET['data']['categories'];
foreach($categories as $array) {
    foreach($array as $category) {
        echo $category."<br/>";
    }
}
```

According to your comment below:

```
$categories = $_GET['data']['categories'];
foreach($categories as $array) {
    foreach($array as $category) {
        $category = intval($category); // anty-injection, we assumed $category is a number
        echo '<a href="domain.com?'.$category.'">Category #'.$category.'</a><br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to include it in an <a hreg="domain.com?the get data here" />